# How to find routes and the accepted paramters in .NET app?

Tags: c#, .net

I am newby in .NET, I know more about BE development in Vapor. Anyway.

1. How can I find the available routes in a .NET app?
2. How can I know which parameters are accepted.

Thia app here does a transformation from DB to XML stored in an FTP, back and forth. Basically only signals are sent to the app, but I do not know how.

This is the file structure:

[image]

And I found some "route-like" lines here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using ptoolApi.Models.IFS;
using ptoolApi.Services;

namespace ptoolApi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddDbContext<ifsContext>(opts => opts.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionString:IFS"]));

            services.AddScoped<ISqliteService, SqliteService>();

            services.AddSwaggerGen(swagger =>
            {
                swagger.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Title = "pTool API",
                    Version = "v2.1.5",
                    Description = "Tool to convert PFB plist file to a sqlite DB, and vice versa"
                });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseSwagger();

            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
#if DEBUG
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "pTool API");
#elif DEVELOPMENT
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/dev/ptooldb/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "pTool API");
#elif STAGE
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/stage/ptooldb/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "pTool API");
#elif RELEASE
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/ptooldb/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "pTool API");
#endif
            });

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Is here `/swagger/v1/swagger.json` a route? And what is the accepted arguments?

---

Meantime I tried

- http://localhost:50491/swagger
- http://localhost:50491/swagger/index.html
- send POST with this parameter

```
{
    "xmltodb": false,
    "dbtoxml": true,
    "airlineID": 2901,
    "deploy": false,
    "XamarinMigration": false,
    "environment": "prod"
}
```

But all is refused, though I found these line under controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
        public RedirectResult Get()
        {
            return RedirectPermanent("/swagger/index.html");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Post(PToolInput input)
        {

            try
            {
                Globals.WriteToLog("Start the connection");
```

Answer (score 0):

The "Routes" are in the Controllers folder. There are classes called Controllers there which have methods, that can represent an action (a url). Swagger is a tool to scaffold the api and create a OpenApi documentation for it.

Answer (score 0):

[Swagger](https://swagger.io/) is a tool (language?) used to describe/document APIs. I think all .NET/.NET Core APIs by default include this tool as part of [Swashbuckle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio).

If you debug the API, and navigate to the `/swagger` endpoint, it should display you the Swagger documentation of your API. Which I think in turn, will satisfy what you are looking for - the routes (endpoints) of the API and what parameters they take, etc. These are your Controller methods essentially, which can be found in your `Controllers` folder.

An example of a basic controller method may look like:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("test")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public List<MyTestModel> Get()
    {
        List<MyTestModel> models = new List<MyTestModel>
        {
            new MyTestModel
            {
                SomeString = "Hello world!",
                SomeInteger = 101,
                SomeBool = true
            }
        };

        return models;
    }
}
```

Notice how the class is decorated with the `Route` attribute.  This defines the route for all the controller methods found in the controller.  In this particular example, the *route* (or URI really) would be `https://<root>/test/`.  Performing a GET against this resource would yield the following JSON:

```json
[
    {
        "someString": "Hello world!",
        "someInteger": 101,
        "someBool": true
    }
]
```

Alternatively, you can have another method with the decorator of `[HttpPost]`, and performing a POST against the same URI would execute said method.

For more information, see the [Microsoft documentation on routing in ASP.Net Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0) - it's very detailed!

Comment: It does not work. I used the one listed under controller.

Comment: @János can you post the rest of the particular controller class you were looking at? Also, you said the request were _refused_, was that a HTTP 403 or something else?